# Uploaded image path from server

Tags: java, filepath, struts-1

i uploaded an image from client to server...i need to save the server path in database...

i saved the image sucesssfully..i have a problem in path

I need to save the path like this in database

```
https://localhost/...../filename
```

but in mine the path was taken like this

```
d:/...../filename
```

this is my code

`String root = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

File path = new File(root + "/images/");

if (!path.exists()) 

{

    boolean status = path.mkdirs();

}

File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + vehicleId +".png");

 String pathString=uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath();

item.write(uploadedFile);`

Please sort out my problem..
thanking you..

Comment: So stop saving the real path of the file in the DB and only save the part that's relative to the app. That said, uploading *into* an app is a recipe for disaster, since redeploys might delete them, and if you deploy a war, you *can't*. Store them elsewhere, and either stream them back, or make the storage directory accessible, etc.

Comment: thanks @DaveNewton suppose i deploy the above code and put it on server means, is it take the server image path instead of this    "d:/...../filename"

Comment: I know what you mean, and I told you how to fix it--only save the part that isn't app-relative. You also need to take duplicate filenames in to account. And all the other stuff I said.